# Remove application from other application

Tags: android

I try to remove application from another application in android but When I run below code I got a this error **"The application was not found in the list of installed applications"** how can I solve this problem furthermore try to remove application has a many package which can I use?

```
Uri packageURI = Uri.parse("package:com.example.anke");
Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageURI);
startActivity(uninstallIntent);
```

Comment: To delete the app ypu dont give the `classes packages name`.
Application has only one package name(which is different from the classes package names[classes holder]), check it from the `AndroidManifest` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code and see your application's package name in your device and use this package name which you want to remove application.

```
final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final List pkgAppsList = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for whether particular application is installed or not like below

```
private boolean isApplicationInstalled(String packagename, Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        packageManager.getPackageInfo(packagename, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        return true;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you get true go for uninstall, if false then application is not installed.